# how to not enter if statement inside a loop if it have been executed

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I have a for loop, and inside it i have if statement.

In my Excel I have a list that contains each value one time. Once I found it i don't want the code to even check the conditional, i want it to skip this part of the if statement completely each time the loop is executed, is it possible?

Here is my code and list:
[image: Here is my code and list]

the first iteration of the loop will find that "c" is the value so it will do what inside it (xc = i)

I don't want the code to even check "ElseIf Cells(1, i) = "c" again, like the following image, is this possible?

[image: what i want]

code as text:

```
Sub test()

Dim i, xa, xb, xc As Integer

For i = 1 To 5

    If Cells(i, 1) = "a" Then
      xa = i
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" Then
      xb = i
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "c" Then
      xc = i
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the code as text, not as image.

Comment: Why does it matter if your list only contains unique values?

Comment: @TimWilliams efficiency and time. I have 60 ElseIf

Comment: @trincot - I edited the original post, check the code as text there

Comment: If you want to be more efficient then read the cell value into a variable before entering the If block

Comment: @TimWilliams can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

My initial interpretation of your need was "if the code hits 'c' again, just don't act".

To do so, you could modify the logic as follows:

```
ElseIf (xc = 0) And (Cells(i, 1) = "c") Then
```

This way, as soon as `xc` is set, the first boolean expression would be False, and the overall condition would not ever be met again. As mentioned by @TimWilliams, VBA would still evaluate the second boolean expression, unlike other languages that feature short-circuiting options. @Gene's answer describes a way around this. Typically, for better performance, you would evaluate the simple conditions first, before resorting to costly ones.

**Additional notes**

In VBA, you must give a type to each variable. In your `Dim` line, only xc is an Integer, while the other variables are Variants.

An unqualified `Cells()` call operates on the currently active worksheet, which might not be the expected one. Suggestion: qualify `Cells()` with the CodeName of your worksheet. The CodeName is what you see or specify under a worksheet's `(Name)` property as seen from the Visual Basic editor. For example, if `(Name)` is `Sheet1`, use `Sheet1.Cells()`. This will only work if the code resides in the same workbook as `Sheet1`. If the code is behind the worksheet itself, you can even use `Me.Cells()`.

When dealing with cell values as your code does, VBA is (silently) being nice and understands that, among the numerous properties of the `Range` class, `Value` is what you are interested in. It is better practice, however, to explicitly state the target property, such as in `Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value`.

**EDIT**

Knowing the values will be distinct and that there are about 60 of them, I suggest you simply use a Dictionary, as shown below, to get each value's row in one go, without a cascade of `If`s:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dict As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To 5
        dict(Cells(i, 1).Value) = i
    Next

    Debug.Print dict("a") '4
    Debug.Print dict("b") '2
    Debug.Print dict("c") '1
    'Etc.
End Sub
```

Comment: you are absolutely right about the additional notes, this was just for the example

Comment: regarding: ElseIf (xc = 0) And (Cells(i, 1) = "c"), it will still check it. my list have unique values so it will be the same as my solution.

I don't want it to even check the Boolean.
what i mean is, you wrote: ElseIf (TRUE/FALSE) And (TRUE/FALSE) then

I want to ignore it altogether, and send this ElseIf to a section in the code that won't be touched anymore. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @TimWilliams - I thought OP was interested in the first positions of non-unique values. Now we also know there are about 60 of them and obviously there are way better ways to go about this.

Comment: @Excelosaurus i tried your code and works fine and answer at the question 100%. Nice :) .. For me is the first time that i see the scripting.Dictionary...

Comment: @Excelosaurus - for your first code example, it's worth noting that VBA doesn't "short-circuit" boolean tests which are And-ed together - all of the statements are evaluated, and then the And is applied.  So even if xc=0, the value of the cell is still checked.

Comment: oops "even if xc!=0..."

Comment: @TimWilliams My interpretation of OP's need (despite the litteral description) is "if the code hits 'c' again, just don't act". Will edit to make this clear. Pity we don't have AndAlso / OrElse in VBA.

Comment: @Excelosaurus - seemed like they wanted the *whole test* to go away once it had passed once

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question you can try this code:

```
Sub test()
Dim i, xa, xb, xc As Integer
Dim a, b, c As Boolean

a = False 
b = False
c = False

For i = 1 To 5

    If Cells(i, 1) = "a" And a <> True Then

        xa = i
        a = True
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" And b <> True Then

        xb = i
        b = True
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "c" And c <> True Then

        xc = 1
        c = True

    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Boolean variable is setted true for example only when the cells(i,1)="a" and after the next "a" value are skipped...

hope this helps

Comment: I don't want it to even check the ElseIf.
what i mean is, you wrote: ElseIf (TRUE/FALSE) And (TRUE/FALSE) then

I want to ignore it altogether, and send this ElseIf to a section in the code that won't be touched anymore. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to "mod" Ferdinando's code so it's a bit more "readable", I think. The main (the substantive) difference between this version and Ferdinando's or Excelosaurus' is that the cell is not even tested once the value is detected. Remember that the question was: **I don't want the code to even check "ElseIf Cells(1, i) = "c" again...**  So, this version does exactly that.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, xa As Integer, xb As Integer, xc As Integer
Dim aFound As Boolean, bFound As Boolean, cFound As Boolean
Dim r As Range

For i = 1 To 5
    Set r = Cells(i, 1)
    If Not aFound Then
        If r = "a" Then xa = i: aFound = True
    ElseIf Not bFound Then
        If r = "b" Then xb = i: bFound = True
    ElseIf Not cFound Then
        If r = "c" Then xc = i: cFound = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you're right but let me rephrase that: "I don't want the code to even check a Boolean statement" (regardless of how it looks), I'm basically looking for a solution to mark this part of the code as ignored for the rest of the code. I can't of anything like that and that's why i'm asking here

Comment: @Assaf; Great, any of the proposed solutions should be suitable for you in this case. Happy coding!

Comment: @Assaf - I am struggling to understand your need. To me, it seems you want the row position of each value, hence my latest edit. Of course, whenever the loop runs, the whole dictionary will be rebuilt. What is it that you want to skip and why?

Comment: let's say i=3, "c" and "b" already been "found". the value now is "0" and the loop will still check "ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" each time. it's not very efficient. when I have a for loop that runs 40 times and inside the if I have like 60 ElseIf it takes time. I mean, it's only a minute but i'd like to know more for future projects

Comment: @Assaf; As you might have noticed, the code above would not check "ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" each time if "b" is already found. I also made a small edit to make it run yet more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of 60 ElseIfs. Please examine the code below. In order to test it, create a worksheet called "TestSheet" and enter your A1:A5 to cells H2:H6.

```
Sub TestSpike()
    ' 06 Jan 2019

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Items As Variant
    Dim Spike As String
    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    Items = Split("c|b|0|a|1", "|")
    With Worksheets("TestSheet").Columns("H")
        For R = 2 To 6
            Tmp = CStr(.Cells(R).Value)
            If InStr(1, Spike, Tmp, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Spike = Spike & "|" & Tmp

                On Error Resume Next
                i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Tmp, Items, 0)
                If Err Then
                    MsgBox Tmp & " wasn't found in Array"
                Else
                    MsgBox "i = " & i & " = Item " & Tmp
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

The code has a "Spike". Each item is first checked against the Spike. If it is found there no further tests are carried out. Else, it is added to the Spike.
New items, after being added to the Spike, are checked against the Array "Items" which would hold your 60 elements, separated by Chr(124) thus, Split("c|b|0|a|1", "|"). I use the worksheet function MATCH to look for the item in the array. The result is an index number (or an error, if not found). You can use this index number in a Select Case statement to process each item distinct from others, basically the same way as you now process it when the If statement returns True.
One idea you may find useful with this kind of setup is to use the index from the Match function to return a value from another array. The other array might, for example, contain function names and you use Application.Run to call a different function for each item. This would run significantly faster than examining 60-odd Select Case statements.